# SQL para encontrar número dentro de um intervalo de dois campos de tabela Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Minha tabela Mysql possui os seguintes campos:

```
id;
num_min;
num_max;
```

O usuário informará um número e preciso verificar se esse número está no intervalo entre a coluna num_min e num_max da tabela.

Tentei com between mas não deu certo!

É possível fazer isso utilizando diretamente uma query mysql ou tem que ser feito via php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se sua sintaxe do between está correta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_nome WHERE $valor BETWEEN num_min AND num_max;
```

Também há essa opção:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_nome WHERE $valor > num_min AND $valor < num_max;
```

Mas between é melhor, poste como você fez (código), o erro pode estar no php

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!